# difference between com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockListActivity.class and ListView

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

Tell me difference between com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockListActivity and ListView.i am including this library https://github.com/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock.
but i dont understand that sherlocklistactivity is better than ListView.

Comment: i also could not know how to use sherlocklistactivity.

Answer (score 2):

> ActionBarSherlock is an extension of the support library designed to
>   facilitate the use of the action bar design pattern across all
>   versions of Android with a single API.
>
> Donations & Merhandise The library will automatically use the native
>   action bar when appropriate or will automatically wrap a custom
>   implementation around your layouts. This allows you to easily develop
>   an application with an action bar for every version of Android from
>   2.x and up.

Basically the difference is that one has ActionBar on android 2.x while the other one does not. Tough with how far Google has gotten with their support library, I would say that Sherlock's library is deprecated and obsolute.

Also a lot of developers (including me) no longer support android 2.x

**EDIT:**
The difference between a ListAcitvity and ListView is that one is obviously an Activity and the other one an View so they have different methods available and also different purposes. The purpose of Activity is to display Views while the View is responsible for drawing itself. `ListActivity` however is different between a normal one is that `ListActivity` also provides methods to display Views in a `ListView` and handling their click events.

Comment: its true that its available for android2.x and mostly app not designed for android2.x or android 3.x.

Comment: but bojan kseneman my question is about listview , or sherlocklistactivity difference? have u ever use sherlocklistactivity?

Comment: I have updated the answer. I have never used SherlockListActivity nor normal ListActivity as the problems I have to solve are far more complex than the ones you can solve with a (Sherlock)ListActivity

Comment: one more question is that difference between android.app.ListActivity and
com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockListActivity? is SherlockListActivity is better than app.ListActivity?

Comment: I have already answered that. One has actionbar on outdated phones, other one not.